# Error trying to allocate a bidimensional array in C

Tags: c, windows, gcc, memory, memory-management

Problem informations:
Compiler: mingw32-gcc.exe (tdm-1) 4.7.1
CLI: gcc z:\ES16\main.c -o main.exe
Code tested:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define DIM 3

void print_matrix(int**  _mtx);
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int **mtx;
    mtx = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*)*DIM);
    for (i=0;i<DIM;i++)
    {
        mtx[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int*)*DIM);
    }

    for(i=0;i<DIM*DIM;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<DIM;j++)
        {
           *((*(mtx)) + (i * DIM + j))= (int)(rand() % 10 + 1);
        }


    }
    print_matrix(mtx);

    free(mtx);

    return 0;
}

void print_matrix(int** _mtx)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<DIM;j++)
        {
            printf("%d  ",*((*(_mtx)) + (i * DIM + j)));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Below we have some points that make us think that the problem is Windows and not the compiler:

1. The program works under Linux without problems
2. Works on Windows 10 Code::Blocks 16.01 with its default compiler
3. Works with Code::Blocks 12.11 and mingw32-gcc.exe (tdm-1) 4.7.1

> Despite all the things above the program doesn't work launched from
>   windows deafult shell.

Occasionally the programs crashes without printing the matrix and sometimes it crashes after printing part of the matrix.
Always without any particular reason.

Considering all these things the problem seems to be Windows so we would like to have some clarification on the problem.

Comment: So you don't even consider possibility your code has a bug? Nice. I see at least two of them...

Comment: [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) says: `==25847== Invalid read of size 4
==25847==    at 0x100000DB1: print_matrix (mem31.c:41)
==25847==    by 0x100000E72: main (mem31.c:27)
==25847==  Address 0x100a7f5a8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 24 alloc'd
==25847==    at 0x100007E81: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==25847==    by 0x100000E17: main (mem31.c:15)`.

Comment: I see at least two **enormous** bugs.

Comment: And also: `==25847== Invalid read of size 4
==25847==    at 0x100000DB1: print_matrix (mem31.c:41)
==25847==    by 0x100000E72: main (mem31.c:27)
==25847==  Address 0x100a7f5a8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 24 alloc'd
==25847==    at 0x100007E81: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==25847==    by 0x100000E17: main (mem31.c:15)`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Valgrind is a too heavy artillery for this ..

Comment: New Windows OS bug that nobody else has seen, or UB... you choose.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Using `valgrind` is one way of finding problems in other people's code without needing to think very hard.  Which, since I'm supposed to be paying attention to a meeting is a good thing for me.  But it is a beautiful demonstration that testing cannot show the absence of bugs.

Comment: Also, there is no "bidemensional" (i.e. 2D) array anywhere in your code, nor anything much like one.

Comment: I wrote "possible". Can you correct my code?

Comment: ^^ what John is saying is that an array of pointers to arrays is NOT a 2D array.

Comment: First use the debugger and provide a clear statement where the bug appears, under which conditions, etc. This is no "we debug your code" service.

Comment: OK, first thing: Look at which types you are allocating. Is that what you intend? You are storing `int`s, but where is allocation for type `int`?

Comment: Your row allocations are wrong. And your initialization and print loops index your matrix incorrectly.

Comment: @Olaf: Unfortunately you're wrong.  SO is a Mechanical Turk for debugging. And I have a bit of shame that I occasionally contribute to that problem.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I always wonder what people do for reps or money ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 issues found:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define DIM 3

void print_matrix(int**  _mtx);
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int **mtx;
    mtx = malloc(sizeof(int*)*DIM);
    for (i=0;i<DIM;i++)
    {
        mtx[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*DIM);  /* 1: sizeof int, not int* */
    }

    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++)  /* 2: just DIM, not DIM*DIM */
    {
        for(j=0;j<DIM;j++)
        {
           mtx[i][j]= (int)(rand() % 10 + 1); /* 3: i * DIM + j   magic is used if you have a 1 dimension array, but want to access it as two dimensions */
        }
    }
    print_matrix(mtx);

    free(mtx);

    return 0;
}

void print_matrix(int** _mtx)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<DIM;j++)
        {
            printf("%d  ",_mtx[i][j]); /* 4: same as 3 */
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea why it works without any problem under linux?

Comment: Pure luck. A malloc() call might return more memory than you requested, and how much more (if any) depends on the libc implementation